# How Can I Cut/Copy a Table (Not Just Its Contents) in Libre Office Writer

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

Every page I can find on the internet has the following instructions for moving a table in Libre Office Writer:

1. Focus on the table
2. From the Table menu choose Select > Table
3. Hit `CTRL + X` (or perform a "cut" some other way)
4. Move the cursor to the desired location of the table
5. Hit `CTRL + V` (or perform a "paste" some other way)

But when I try to follow these instructions, they don't work: Libre Office pastes the *contents* of my table, but it leaves the table itself behind (now empty).

Is there any way I can actually move the entire table *and* its contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the answer to my own question.  If you add a single character of text on the line just before the table itself, then select that line *and* the table, Open Office will correctly allow you to cut both of them without leaving the table structure behind.

You can then paste the single character and the table to the desired location, and both the table's structure *and* content will come along.  Simply delete the character of text after that and you're set.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the preferred workaround for this bug.  The other method is to copy and paste and then delete the original table.  See https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/257/how-can-i-move-tables-in-writer/ for a full discussion.

Answer (score 0):

When pasting the table press Ctrl + Shift + V and select "HyperText Markup Language(HTML)" in dialog box. The table itself should be pasted along with its contents.

Comment: What operating system/browser does this work on?  For me `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `V` doesn't bring up any options at all.

Comment: For me it works on Fedora 37 with Libre Office 7.4.6.2.

Comment: Another way that works for me without keyboard shortcut is "Mouse right click" -> "Paste Special" -> "More Options..." -> "HyperText Markup Language(HTML)".